# Как поменять местами байты элементов массива?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть массив, в котором каждый элемент является двухбайтовым словом. Как поменять местами первый и второй байт каждого элемента?

Comment: Вы можете привести пример входного и ожидаемого массива (по 3-5 элементов)? Известна ли `Endianness` до / во время конверсии?

Comment: В каком python типе хранятся элементы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Имея [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) массив, в котором каждый элемент хранится в минимум двух байтах, чтобы поменять порядок байт, достаточно вызвать [`array.byteswap()` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array.byteswap):

```
>>> import array
>>> a = array.array('h', [1, 32767])
>>> a.tobytes()
b'\x01\x00\xff\x7f'
>>> a.byteswap()
>>> a.tobytes()
b'\x00\x01\x7f\xff'
>>> a
array('h', [256, -129])
```

Видно что числа были сохранены в массив используя родной порядок байт (`sys.byteorder` равно `'little'` на моей системе—от "младшего к старшему"). После вызова `.byteswap()` порядок байт поменялся на "от старшего к младшему", что изменило хранимые значения (которые всегда в `sys.byteorder` интерпретируются):

```
>>> import sys
>>> 1 .to_bytes(2, sys.byteorder)
b'\x01\x00'  # от "младшего к старшему"
>>> 1 .to_bytes(2, 'big')
b'\x00\x01'  # "от старшего к младшему"
>>> int.from_bytes(_, 'little') # интепретируя как от "младшего к старшему"
256
```

То же API работает и для `numpy` массивов:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array([1, 32767], dtype='h')
>>> a
array([    1, 32767], dtype=int16)
>>> a.tobytes()
b'\x01\x00\xff\x7f'
>>> a.byteswap(True) # inplace
array([ 256, -129], dtype=int16)
>>> a.tobytes()
b'\x00\x01\x7f\xff'
```

Видно, что идентичные результаты получаются.

---

Если у вас есть Питон список с Питон числами `[1, 32767]`, то понятие порядка байт большого смысла не имеет. Как фактически Python int в памяти представлен зависит от реализации и для большинства приложений это не имеет значения. К примеру, в CPython, `int` состоит из `sys.int_info.bits_per_digit`-битных цифр, каждая из которых занимает `sys.int_info.sizeof_digit` байт, где эти цифры идут от младшей к старшей позиции и [абсолютное значение Python `int` равно](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8b7c89539e21a26ceb52a2cd617c2563e0c03dbe/Include/longintrepr.h#L70-L88):

```
SUM(for i=0 through abs(ob_size)-1) ob_digit[i] * 2**(SHIFT*i)
```

Answer (score 2):

Немного магии с числами. Сначала разобьём двухбайтовое число `value` на два однобайтовых:

```
lo = value % 256
hi = value // 256
```

Теперь соберём обратно в двухбайтовое:

```
value == hi * 256 + lo # всегда должно быть верно
rev_value =  lo * 256 + hi # то, что хотим по условию, поменяли байты
```

В итоге, если записать короче в виде функции:

```
rev_bytes = lambda v: v % 256 * 256 + v // 256
```

Применив эту функцию ко всем элементам списка, например, с помощью `map`, мы получим полноценное решение.

**Замечание 1**:
Для увеличения производительности это следовало бы записать через логические побитовые операции, заменив `i // 256` на `i >> 8`, `i * 256` на `i << 8`, и `+` на `|`:

```
rev_bytes = lambda v: ((v % 256) << 8) | (v >> 8)
```

**Внимание**: осторожнее с порядком следования операций, можно получить неожиданный результат, если неправильно расставить скобки или вовсе этого не делать.

**Замечание 2**:
Ещё одной возможной оптимизацией здесь является меморизация. Если эту функцию надо будет применять очень много раз - будет быстрее один раз сохранить её результаты для *всех* двухбайтовых чисел в массив, а вызов функции заменить взятием нужного элемента из этого массива.

---

**UPD:**

Пусть `MyArray` есть список двухбайтовых чисел, хранимых в `int`. Тогда новый массив будет таким:

```
NewArray = list(map(lambda v: ((v % 256) << 8) | (v >> 8), MyArray))
```

`map` применит функцию смены байт местами к каждому элементу `MyArray`. `list` сделает из него список.

Comment: если не сложно, напишите полный код

Comment: 1- Какой тип у `value`? Python int не является "двухбайтовым словом". 2- О производительности `i * 256` по сравнению с `i << 8` не стоит без измерений говорить (даже на С не ясно есть ли разница, не говоря про Питон) 3- упомяните явно поведение для отрицательных чисел 4- `v % 256` можно как `v & 0xFF` записать.

Answer (score 1):

```
def reverse(input):
    L = len(input)
    if L%2 <> 0:
        return 'Error' #Ошибка в случае когда L не кратно 2
    else:
        Res = ''
        L = L//2
        for i in range(L):
            T = input[i*2] + input[i*2+1]
            Res = T + Res
            T = ''
        return(Res);
```

`Arr` - ваш массив чисел (массив строк, каждая строка вида `A1F6...`, в вашем случае `A65D`, к примеру)

Код вызова:

```
ArrLength = len(Arr)
for i in range(ArrLength):
    Arr[i] = reverse(Arr[i])
```

Comment: Надо немного подправить код: заменить `<>` на `!=`. И ещё хорошо бы прикрутить преобразование в hex и обратно с добавлением необходимого числа нулей в начало строки.

Comment: @diversenok тогда придётся как-то вычислять, с какой стороны добавлять нули. Не так ли?

Comment: Просто двухбайтовые числа, записанные в виде строки, не всегда имеют длину 4 символа. Ладно, напишу сам: `IntToHex = lambda a: '0' * (6 - len(hex(a))) + hex(a)[2:]`

Comment: Мой - самый простой вариант)

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать "сериализовать" Python элемент в бинарное сишное представление, затем поменять местами байты.

Предполагаю, что элементы хранятся в виде чисел.

```
from struct import pack, unpack

def reorder_bytes( value ):
    return unpack( "H", pack( "H", value )[::-1] )[0]


# модуль struct используется для конвертации С структур в python объекты
# H --- unsigned int16
# pack с "H" сконвертирует python int в бинарную строку длиной в 2 байта, соответствующую Си представление unsigned int16
# unpack возвращает tuple из распакованных данных, нужный нам результат будет в первом элементе.
```

Comment: Эта функция возвращает `tuple` с одним элементом, хорошо бы его распаковать.

Comment: Добавил распаковку.